# odoo 8 mass confirm manufacture

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

I am mass confirming manufacturing orders(MOs) that are in draft state and i am using following code that is executed from more button after selecting MOs in manufacturing order tree view:

```
@api.multi
def mass_action(self):
    mo_obj = self.env['mrp.production']
    mo_ids = self.env.context.get('active_ids')
    if self.confirm:
        domain = [('state', '=', 'draft'),
                  ('id', 'in', mo_ids)]
        draft_mo_lst = mo_obj.search(domain)
        for x in draft_mo_lst:
            x.action_confirm()
```

Everything works when i press "Force reservation" if the MO is created from sale order (they are already confirmed when made from there).

If i confirm MOs that are created with create button or function from another template then after using this wizard the production does not go to ready state after pressing "Force reservation" button. It seems that it reserves the products and assigns them in stock move database table but MO itself does not change state to ready. The MO seems to be stuck after that.

Am i missing something or do i need to do it somehow differently?

Comment: what does self.confirm means in a multi way? you should iterate self if you want to achieve that

Comment: it is a boolean field that needs to be checked before for the wizard to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code fixes the problem. The action_confirm() function had to be called out through workflow signal "button_confirm".

```
@api.multi
def mass_action(self):
    mo_obj = self.env['mrp.production']
    mo_ids = self.env.context.get('active_ids')
    from openerp import workflow
    if self.confirm:
        domain = [('state', '=', 'draft'),
                  ('id', 'in', mo_ids)]
        draft_mo_lst = mo_obj.search(domain)
        for x in draft_mo_lst:
            workflow.trg_validate(self._uid, 'mrp.production', x.id, 'button_confirm', self._cr)
```